# Using XMMatrixLookAtLH - trying to face a point, but doesn't work/crashes?

Tags: c++, matrix, directxmath

I'm using this code for my Entity class:

```
void Entity::Face(FXMVECTOR target)
{
XMVECTOR up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


up = XMVector3Transform(up, Rotation);


Rotation = XMMatrixLookAtLH(Translation, target, up); //Rotation is a XMMATRIX, Translation is a XMVECTOR
}
```

And trying to get it to face another entity.Basically I'm doing this:

```
Entity a = //....
Entity b = //.......
a.Face(b.Translation);
```

And what happens is one of 3 things:
1.The function crashes, because of an assertion
2.Entity 'a' is misplaced in a weird position
3.Entity 'a' dissapears

This damn function XMMatrixLookAtLH has been the source of problems all over my project, everywhere I used it I had to spend hours to get it to work properly.

If I create the rotation matrix with XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYawFromVector, it works perfectly, however I NEED to get it to face directly at the point it's been given and I don't know how to get it to work.Please someone give me an advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the assertion that is failing exactly? That's the clue to what the problem may be.

```
assert(!XMVector3Equal(EyeDirection, XMVectorZero()));
assert(!XMVector3IsInfinite(EyeDirection));
assert(!XMVector3Equal(UpDirection, XMVectorZero()));
assert(!XMVector3IsInfinite(UpDirection));
```

Since you are using XMVECTOR and XMMATRIX as class members, have you made sure that your class Entity is always allocated with 16-byte alignment? This is only guaranteed in x64 (64-bit) native programs by default. If you are writing a 32-bit app, you need to use XMLoad*/XMStore* functions and avoid using XMVECTOR and XMMATRIX directly in your class. Make sure you know the difference between when you get a C assertion breakpoint to fire and when you are actually getting an exception thrown like 'access violation' due to alignment.

You may find that using [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) (in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929)) more natural to use than directly using DirectXMath, but it is generally designed around RH coordinates.